# SOAP - PHP is possible to change 'ns1' tag name?

Tags: php, xml, soap

I need send a XML with this format:

```
<soapenv:Body>
<loc:amount>
  <loc:user>user_name</loc:user>
  <loc:charge>
    <description>description_text</description>
  </loc:charge>
</loc:amount>
```

I have generate the XML body with soapVar, but I cant change "ns1" tag.
Source:

```
$var = '<loc:amount> <loc:user>user_name</loc:user> <loc:charge> <description>description_text</description> </loc:charge> </loc:amount>';    
$params[0] = new SoapVar($var,XSD_ANYXML,'amount','http://mydomain.cm');
```

And the header result is this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://mydomain.cm" xmlns:ns2="http://header_domain.cm">
```

I need this result:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:loc="http://mydomain.cm" xmlns:ns2="http://header_domain.cm">
```

Is possible to change 'ns1' tag to 'loc'??

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Namespace prefix names are insignificant; it is only through their binding to a namespace value that they derive meaning.   No conformant XML processor will care about the specific namespace prefix names; you should not either.

Comment: Ok, but It's a API code and I need that the XML result as same as example, In case of I have a bad response, server error.

Comment: Your comment indicates that you did not understand my answer.  You're either dealing with a non-conformant XML processor (possible but unlikely), or you're misinterpreting the error you're receiving.

Comment: @xandra: If for some reason it is important to you, can't you just change the ns name in your XML string so that it matches the name that SoapVar generates ? (i.e `<ns1:AMOUNT><ns1:user> ...` )

Comment: @kjhughes That doesn't help if you contact a Server which "hard coded" needs a defined namespace name.

Comment: @AlexanderOpitz: Such a service is broken.  It doesn't follow the rules, which means its clients have to be provided new rules and cannot use tools that follow the standard rules.  Neither I nor most here nor standards-following libraries nor a whole body of example code and Q/A are going to help you or OP debug interactions with a third party black box with idiosyncratic, or undefined, rules.

Comment: @kjhughes The rule, in this example, is defined by "use loc as namespace", the rule is stupid but it seams the server here can't be changed. So it seams it follows the standard rules plus one stupid extra rule. Blaming around this, doesn't help.

Comment: @AlexanderOpitz: We're talking about namespace prefixes, not "loc as namespace", whatever that means, and my point is to educate about what's standard.  Standard plus N exceptions for any positive number N is by definition non-standard.  You evidently don't like this answer, but that's the way standards work.  I suggest you post a new question if you're still in need of help of some sort.  OP was satisfied with this answer four years ago, and you are not contributing anything helpful by continuing these comments at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I've such an issue with UPnP Devices, which use "u" as default namespace-prefix and I need to change it from ns1. As I also found no better solution, I'll post my solution here.

```
class UpnpSoapClient extends SoapClient {

public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $oneWay = 0)
{
    // Some fucking UPnP Devices need the fucking u as namespace-prefix ... WTF?
    if (preg_match('/xmlns:ns1=/', $request)) {
        $request = preg_replace('/xmlns:ns1=/', 'xmlns:u=', $request, 1);
        $request = preg_replace('/ns1:/', 'u:', $request);
    }
    return parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version);
}
```

}

Comment: *which use "u" as default namespace*  No, `u` is not a default namespace; it is a namespace prefix.  As I [answered four years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39472259/290085), namespace prefixes are insignificant apart from the namespace value to which they're bound.  There is a greater chance that you're misunderstanding XML namespaces than there is that the service you're using would be so broken as to require a specific namespace prefix.  And if you have found such a broken service, adding such a hack as this on top of their hack is propagating the problem and asking for future failures.

Comment: Ok, default namespace is not correct (as it would be defined with <element xmlns="namespace">, so let me rephrase this to "default UPnP namespace-prefix".